# Color formatting Pie Charts in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: ssrs

I have a pie chart with Categories(Male, Female) with Percentages. If I want to color format Male and Female portion of the chart, what is the approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the Properties pane.
2. On the design surface, click the chart. The properties for the chart object are displayed in the Properties pane.
3. The object name (Chart1 by default) appears in the drop-down list at the top of the Properties pane.
4. In the Chart section, for the Palette property, select a new palette from the drop-down list.